# how to hide half the homepage with a show more button WORDPRESS

Tags: wordpress

So I have been searching for a good plugin but was unable to find any - On the homepage of the WP website that I am working on, I want to hide half the page and want to add a button and in middle of the page at the end of the first half that would say "Show More" - When the visitor clicks that button, the rest of the page should show. The button would then go to the end of the page saying "Show Less". The page is static and is just some text and images, nothing complex.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this putting a html block and writing:

```
<!--nextpage-->
```

you can read more about this on:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Styling_Page-Links

and to get other solutions you can try:

https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/automatically-paginate-posts/

https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/sgr-nextpage-titles/

https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/page-links-single-page-option/

I hope this will help you to get what you want.

Comment: Hi there, thank you for the answer - however I am not looking to paginate the homepage - Since it's a static page, im looking for some sort of AJAX or JQUERY plugin that enables you to see the rest of the page but without having to reload it or having to go on another page

Comment: I will put other answer to leave this here like a posible but not right answer.

Answer (score 0):

You must create a div with css display none. And then in your html code put an  element with a jquery behaviour to display the previously div created. It will be something like:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#show_content_button').click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $('#content_hide_on_home').show();
  });
  $('#hide_content_button').click(function(){
    $('#show_content_button').show();
    $('#content_hide_on_home').hide();
  });
});
```

```css
#content_hide_on_home { display:none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Text on home</p>
<a href="#" id="show_content_button">Show content</a>
<div id="content_hide_on_home">
Your extra content on home
<a href="#" id="hide_content_button">Hide content</a>
</div>
```

I hope this is what you're searching.